Alternative movable Do syllables
Is there a widely used alternative movable Do syllables system?
I started practicing functional ear training with movable Do a while ago and experienced a certain level of success for the first time. Unfortunately, I come from a fixed Do country and this method conflicts with my teacher’s method.
I thought about using English scale degrees instead and converting them to one syllable words (Wa, Tu, Ti, Fo, Fa, Si, Se) so they are easy to sing. However, this method has obvious drawbacks such as having multiple similar sounding degrees, syllables sounding like note names and not supporting chromatic alterations.
I also found this method which seems well thought out but I get the impression it cannot be used to communicate with other musicians as it is too niche.
Is there a recommended alternative? If not, do you think my scale degrees approach is workable? How would you approach singing chromatic alterations with these syllables?

Why not just find a teacher who works with moveable Do?

@Aaron 1. She is also my voice teacher (a very good one) and our ear training and singing lessons work together. 2. I find it difficult to find teachers due to  problems, so once I do I stick by them. I am, however, considering stopping the ear training lessons and working independently with Karpinski’s ear training book instead.

@Aaron in my (very limited) experience, finding someone in a fixed do country who uses movable do is basically impossible.  Imagine if someone told you that you should call the first note of Bach's violin partita "C" because it's the tonic.  It's just confusing.

@phoog Interestingly, historically it was the other way around; because the early-nineteenth-century French couldn’t be bothered to call notes by their place in the current key rather than their place on the staff, they started to call every C “tonic”, ushering in the end of a tradition that had remained unbroken since the Middle Ages. (Okay not tonic but “do”,  but let’s avoid the semantic details of hexachord solmisation here.) On a flippant day I might even be tempted to suggest their modern day fixed-do system is not the cause, but rather the effect of their inability to use movable-do.

On a more positive note, I have often thought those from fixed-do countries might benefit from all the advantages movable-do brings by simply using alternative syllables, so go for it! The original ut re mi was derived by simply taking the first syllable of each of 6 lines of a biblical text, so those syllables are not exactly the product of many long years of pain-staking research into which ones would be the best either. Just take a few syllables and stick with them! If there is a “widely used” alternative I didn’t hear about it.

What about the Hindustani note names? It’s already movable but could cause problems if you ever interact with Hindustani or Carnatic music

@ToddWilcox I will look into them, it’s less likely I will interact with these types of music any time soon.

@11684 weren't the French still using "ut" for C in the 19th century?  And didn't fixed do basically arise with the invention of "si"?  My understanding is that this was added to avoid the necessity of hexachord mutation.  A quick scan of Rameau's treatise suggests that he used basically the same system as in present-day France but with "ut" instead of "do."  That was 1722, well before the 19th century.  (Also ut queant laxis is a hymn, not a biblical text.)

What do you want this system for?  To learn pitches and harmonies?  To learn to sing?  To communicate notes and melodies with other musicians?  —  It's perfectly possible to do all of those with only the letters A–G.  (I don't think any of the teachers, choirs, orchestras, or bands I've been involved with have used any sort of solfege, just the letters — with occasional Nashville numbers in some bands.)  Of course, you can use any system you like on your own, but in some regions all other musicians will probably be using letters.

Get used to the system used in the country where you live now. It will not only let you take the lessons now, but also make it easier to work with other local musicians. And you will still have an edge of knowing the other system too.

@HNHN, you did say so directly, but do you want moveable DO, because associating syllables like TI, DO or FA, MI with relative interval and scale degree relationships improved your "ear", your audiation ability compared to fixed DO?

I never learned moveable Do (so take my comment FWIW) and I like the idea of replacing it with scale degrees.  These numbers are a universal and extremely useful nomenclature.  Not sure about alterations;  do you really have to make everything one syllable?..

@MichaelCurtis Yes, exactly. When it comes to being able to grasp tonality, I think I have really poor ears - many tasks that are considered very basic are in fact quite baffling for me. For instance, I don’t always know if a melody is going up or down - I have to sing it and rely on the physical sensation in my throat to know, or I have to really concentrate for a long time to be able to auralize a specific pitch so I can’t auralize a scale and sing a specific note in it without considerable effort.  I spent quite a lot of time trying to learn intervals without much traction.

@MichaelCurtis For the most part, when people describe “music as a language” I have no idea what they are going on about. But when I stumbled across the idea of movable do suddenly things clicked - I can listen to a simple melody and understand what I’m hearing! I grok the concept of a scale! I can identify patterns that I can remembered and play with! I CAN SIGHT SING!

@Ivan what I like about movable do is not that it’s one syllable, but that I can see how it can naturally extend to any scale / mode (If you don’t want to assume they are all just derivatives of the major scale). I think it’s an internally consistent way to think about tonal music.

@user1079505 I already have problems with local musicians - people who come from the jazz/pop/rock world use C/D/E, classical musicians use Do/Re/Me, I interact with both so routinely have to re-orient my brain to whether “Si” is B or C.

I'd advise against using a 'home made' system - it would be difficult to impossible to communicate with others when you have it off pat.
The two systems (fixed/movable) are really incompatible, as I found out playing with French musos, having had many years immersed in movable do.
If you stick with movable, each note will be relatively correct, and for sight-reading, this is probably more important.
The third option, if one is needed, seems to cover most eventualities - using the actual note names, regardless of keys. It's exact, obviously, and the relationship between notes/names will soon become apparent, just like it does using sol-fa.
A little nugget was that for tuning purposes, the conductor used to ask me to play 'see bemol' for the horns. Initially, I played C♭ (B), as that's how it translated from French to English, but having realised that wasn't quite right(!) the compromise of two fingers pointing downwards made everything crystal clear. Maybe that's another option - sign language that could be used in tandem with the singing..? Not forgetting good old Kodaly, of course.
